# Mongo DB $Set not updating req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
app.put('/accountlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    console.log(req.body));
    db.accounts.findAndModify({
      query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
      update: {$set:req.body}},
      new: true}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
      }
    );
  });
```

Any ideas why this is giving me a problem? Probably something simple.

Comment: The first method seems to allow any data sent to the server into the DB, which seems like a really bad idea ?

Answer (score 2):

There is one extra `}` at the end of this line

```
  update: {$set:req.body}},
```